# Reshape dataframe place categorical in new column for each unique category using R

Tags: r, loops, reshape

Suppose I have the following dataframe

```
 test <- data.frame(items = c("itemA", "itemB","itemC", "itemD"),
          ID = c("1","2","1","3"),
          time = c("11","12","11","13"))

> test
     items ID time
   1 itemA  1   11
   2 itemB  2   12
   3 itemC  1   11
   4 itemD  3   13
```

I'm trying to reshape it so that it collapses on ID. For each unique item a column should be created and the appropriate item should go in each column such that in any 1 item column there is only 1 item. i.e. itemA should not be in the same column as itemB.

Here is a sample of what I'm looking for:

```
> test
     ID time Item1   Item2   Item3    Item4
   1 1   11   itemA    -      itemC    -
   2 2   12    -      itemB    -       -
   4 3   13    -        -      -      itemD
```

Any help aprreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data.table is usually faster... 
if you can live with slightly different column-names, give this a go

```
library( data.table )
dcast( setDT( test ), ID + time ~ items, value.var = "items" )

#    ID time itemA itemB itemC itemD
# 1:  1   11 itemA  <NA> itemC  <NA>
# 2:  2   12  <NA> itemB  <NA>  <NA>
# 3:  3   13  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> itemD
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` to create a sequence column and then `spread` to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>%      
   mutate(rn = paste0("Item", row_number())) %>% 
   spread(rn, items)
# ID time Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
#1  1   11 itemA  <NA> itemC  <NA>
#2  2   12  <NA> itemB  <NA>  <NA>
#3  3   13  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> itemD
```